# How to connect 3W 8Ω speakers to Raspberry Pi 3.5mm audio jack?

Tags: pi-3, gpio, linux, connection, speakers

I have a pair of 3 Watt 8 Ohm speakers.

https://www.amazon.in/JST-interface-Production-Raspberry-Projects/dp/B0738NLFTG

My questions:

1. I want to connect it Raspberry pi 3. How can I do that? From the speaker 2 wires are coming out - one red and one black. Where do I connect these 2 wires?
2. I want to connect directly to raspberry pi. How can I do that?
3. To what pins of Rasp. Pi I need to connect this speaker?

I know that there is (already) an audio jack on the Raspberry Pi board. I only want to to know the steps for connecting the speaker to it and getting some audio output.

Comment: Ah, let me see. This long story might help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976.

Comment: These might also help: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98204/whistle-sound-when-recording-with-usb-sound-card-alsamixer, 

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96756/how-can-i-amplify-my-voice-in-real-time-just-like-a-microphone-does/96760#96760.Cheers.

Comment: And if what you want is to play mp3, this might help: "How can I start an mp3 from the beginning every time a headphone is plugged in?":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106684/how-can-i-start-an-mp3-from-the-beginning-every-time-a-headphone-is-plugged-in. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 . Thanks. ANy idea on how and where to connect the red and black wires coming out pf the speaker ?

Comment: You need to connect an audio amplifier between the audio out on the pi and your speakers.

Comment: Yes, as @CoderMike says, you need to use an audio amplifier such as PAM8403: References: 

(1) Raspberry Pi Zero Audio Circuit - OtherMod 2017jan31
https://othermod.com/raspberry-pi-zero-audio-circuit/

(2) PAM8403 Filterless 3W Class-D Stereo Audio Amplifier
http://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/DFR0119/pam8403.pdf

Comment: And the Rpi 3.5mm to PAM8403 > 3W speaker x 2 connection is like this: 
Connection: (1) Rpi 3.5mm jack(A-5/013) > 3.5mm plug to PAM8403 power amp module, (2) PAM8404 power amp module to 3W speaker x 2 (JST-PH2.0 x 2 connector).

Comment: But the Rpi 3.5mm PWM audio (100Hz to 5kHz pass band) is not very HiFi. You might like to consider using a good quality 20kHz bandwidth USB sound card as suggested by my very first and second references: (3) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&start=25#p1396404. The US$12 cheapy Ugreen USB sound card can select the following modes: (a) HiFi raw, (b) music, (c) film (surround sound), (c) computer gaming to suit your applications.

Comment: As I said, whether to use Rpi PWM audio with 3.5mm output, or USB HiFi stero sound card also with 3.5mm output depends on your applications.  Furthermore, if you are going to use an USB sound card, you might throw away your speakers without amplifier and get  a PC compatible "computer speaker" with built in power amp, ie, no PAM8403. But if you wish to DIY with PAM8403, I would recommend PAM8610 with digital volume, standby, and mute control:
(1) "LogiTech Z150 Stero Speakers (3.5mm RMS 3W) HK$149": 
https://www.logitech.com/en-hk/product/multimedia-speakers-z150?crid=47 / to continue, ...

Comment: (2) "PAM8610 Power Amplifier (digital volume control, standby and mute) 1/3":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96756/how-can-i-amplify-my-voice-in-real-time-just-like-a-microphone-does

(3) PAM8610 Power Amplifier (digital volume control, standby and mute) 2/3":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105280/identify-which-microphone-is-on-which-audio-card-using-arecord/105281#105281

(4)PAM8610 Power Amplifier (digital volume control, standby and mute) 3/3":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83405/dac-mcp4725-not-working-with-raspberry.

Comment: If you don't like Rpi's low quality PWM sound, or difficult to setup USB sound card, or messy hardware power amp, but you insist HiFi quality, comprehensive digital controls of volume, standby, mute, you might like to consider the all digital I2S HiFi audio system, such as this: "Adafruit I2S Audio Bonnet for Raspberry Pi (UDA1334A digital I2S amplifier, 3.5mm stereo headphone jack) - 2018nov": (1) 
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-audio-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi, (2) https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-i2s-audio-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi.pdf?timestamp=1584771886. Cheers.

Comment: BTW, you can also try the US$4 Max98357 I2S amplifier: 
(1) "Max98357 I2S 3W Class D Amplifier for Raspberry Pi - US$4":
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000044546190.html,

(2) "MAX98357 PCM Class D Amplifier Datasheet - Maxim 2019":
https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX98357A-MAX98357B.pdf,

(3) "I2S Recording combined with I2S Playback - Rpi.StackExchange 2019":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/i2s-recording-combined-with-i2s-playback,

(4) "I2S Speaker and microphone - 2018oct":
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=183617#p1385657.

Comment: This is a passive speaker - Reference: (5) Stereo Enclosed Speaker (3W, 8ohm) - CQR0508
http://www.cqrobot.wiki/index.php/Stereo_Enclosed_Speaker_(3_W,_8_ohm)-CQR0508

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a stereo audio amplifier between the Pi’s analogue audio out and your speakers.

If you’re ok soldering something like the following should work and could be powered from the Pi’s 5V.

https://www.amazon.in/Solnoi-Electronics-PAM8406-Amplifier-Potentiometer/dp/B07HDP7222/ref=mp_s_a_1_10?keywords=stereo+amplifier+3w&qid=1584776772&sr=8-10

Comment: Thanks @CoderMike. If you know of any solution which doesn't require soldering?

Comment: @NeedSomeLuck maybe just get some usb powered pc speakers that use 3.5mm headphone and tear them apart - I don't know what your plan is. https://www.postofficeshop.co.uk/office-equipment/audio-equipment/speakers/trust-compact-8-watt-usb-speaker-set-4-watt-rms-20943